# Web Audio node connected to two gain nodes, connected to destination, duplicates speed / pitch

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, html5-audio, web-audio-api

As the title says, if I have an audio node that emits sound and I connect it to two separate GainNodes, which in turn are connected to the Audio Context destination, the sound plays at double speed / double pitch (as if half samples are sent to one gain node and half samples to the other, and the time is halved as well).

I have created an handy jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w5V2f/4/), just drag your sound files in the black rectangle canvas and listen.

```
// audioContext: Web Audio context
// decoded: decoded audioBuffer
// gainNode1, gainNode2: gain nodes
var bSrc = audioContext.createBufferSource();
bSrc.connect (gainNode1);
bSrc.connect (gainNode2);
gainNode1.connect (audioContext.destination);
gainNode2.connect (audioContext.destination);
bSrc.buffer = decoded;
bSrc.loop = false;
// You'll hear two double-speed buffers playing at unison
bSrc.start(0);
```

Is that by design? What I would like is to exactly "duplicate" the sound (that will be sent to two different routes, the fiddle is just a proof-of-concept for a bigger project).

Edit:

- I tested this on Chrome Version 24.0.1312.56 / Ubuntu 12.10 and the behaviour is present.
- The behaviour is also present on Chrome Version 24.0.1312.68 / Ubuntu 12.10
- On Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 / Mac OSX, the Audio API works well and this behaviour is not present.

Could it be a Linux-only issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a Linux implementation issue. It works for me in Chrome on OS X.

Comment: By the way, I would strongly encourage you to file a bug at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list. Move the web forward.

Comment: I tried to, but the issue wizard is keeping responding a 400 error when I submit.

Comment: Reported: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=176808&thanks=176808&ts=1361187635